# How to allow on demand reload of .gsp views and i18n .properties files in Grails load balanced production environment

Tags: grails, view, reload, production-environment

We are running into a very reasonable business requirement to allow changes to the view layer (often text changes) independent of a full build and release cycle (which builds the .war and deploys it across the horizontal fleet of webapp servers, requiring a rolling app restart and performance hit).   In a load balanced, high demand production environment, is there a good way to accomplish this?

Ideally, we'd like the .properties files that have the i18n text and the .gsp files that make up the view layer not be in the .war, and in a centralized spot (like a CDN backed S3 Bucket), similar to how the asset pipeline allows this for this for JS/CSS.  The running grails app should detect a change and reload if and only if there is one with minimal performance overhead outside that reload.  A manual triggered reload would also be fine.

Currently running Grails 2.3.x, but could upgrade to 2.4.x if there are benefits in this area.

Comment: You can externalize gsp files from WAR file. Specially in Grails 2. The side-effect is GSP will not be compiled at tomcat startup but at the first time access. I did that for major project that used CMS to generate GSP.

Unfortunately all that conversation between me and grails developers were in the old site. And are gone now. 

Here is a link that can help you [asset pipeline][1]


  [1]: https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline

Comment: I just wanted to say. It is possible. I did in Grails 2.2. It is just one line in config file. Maybe related to Resources plugin. Sorry couldn't help more.

Comment: @Arjang you can externalize via config, but as you stay they are still compiled on first time access, so I don't think they will reload if you change them?

Comment: Oh yes. I am just trying to help you from memory. We disabled Resources plugin completely then we did something else.  Mark Palmer helped me with that. The author of Resources plugin. http://grails.org/plugin/resources